# array input wrong using strcpy

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The code is supposed to take in as many string as the user wants to put in until they enter EOF. and it is doing that but after i try to ouput the code it comes out with these little half boxes instead of the string.

void sortString(char *s[], int count);

int main(){

```
    int i;
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    int count;
    char** s = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));

    //allows user to keep typing until EOF is reached.
    printf("Here is the list of unsorted names: \n\n");
    for (count = 0; fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin); count++)
    {
        s[count] = malloc((sizeof(buff))*sizeof(char));//allocats memory at s[count].
        strcpy(buff, s[count]);//adds the string in buff to s[count].
        s = (char**) realloc(s, ((sizeof(s) + sizeof(buff)) * sizeof(char*)) + 1);//then reallocats memeory for s to take another string.
    }

    printf("\nCount is %d\n\n", count);
   // Now sort string using sortString function
   // Step 4: implement sortString function for the above-mentioned function declaration
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            printf("%s \n",s[i]);
   }
   sortString(s, count);
   printf("Here is the list of sorted names: \n\n");
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            printf("%s",s[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy(buff, s[count]);//adds the string in buff to s[count].`

No it doesn't.  `strcpy(dest, src)`, so it is copying `s[count]` (which is a buffer full of "random junk") to `buff`.

Comment: Thank you so much I was driving my self up the wall looking for the problem.